# my paytm login task solved using selenium solved but How to know the iframe id from page source?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Getting a popup window when I click login in "paytm.com" but I am not able to enter user name and password

(####How we can know the iframe id  #######)

This is the code

```
public void Test() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\SELENIUM\\Lib\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver= new ChromeDriver();
    // driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://paytm.com/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In / Sign Up")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@ng-hide=’showVerificationScreen’]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='input_0']")).sendKeys("email");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='input_1']")).sendKeys("passwrd");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/div/md-content/button[1]")).click();

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried by replacing `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` with  `driver.switchTo().alert();` ?

Comment: what exception you are facing here? i hope you tried switch to frame correctly as i seen commented line. try with commenting that alert command and un-commenting the switch to frame command.

Comment: Thanku for your answer and ya i will try what u have suggested

Answer (score 0):

That is frame not alert. So have to switch to iframe based on its index or id.
In paytm.com, the login frame is 3rd iframe as per the HTML code. you have to write the code as switchto.iframe(2);

Try below code it work. it will work

```
driver.get("http://www.paytm.com");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In / Sign Up")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame(2); // 2 is the iframe index
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("*******");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("*****");
```

Comment: Thanku soo much and may i know how can i find the iframe id

Comment: @SivaRamaKrishna, it is same like other elements. frame is the tag in your HTML code.

Comment: <iframe id = "xxxxx" ng-hide="showVerificationScreen" ng-src="/v1/api/login?isIframe=true&amp;theme=mp-web" width="715px" height="425px" frameborder="0" border="0" ng-class="homePageScrolledDown? 'fixedhead' : ''" src="/v1/api/login?isIframe=true&amp;theme=mp-web"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException

This clearly conveys no alert present.On spying we get:

```
iframe width="715px" height="425px" frameborder="0" ng-class="homePageScrolledDown? 'fixedhead' : ''" border="0" ng-src="/v1/api/login?isIframe=true&theme=mp-web" ng-hide="showVerificationScreen" src="/v1/api/login?isIframe=true&theme=mp-web"
```

Replace -

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept()
```

with

```
driver.switchTo().frame(2);
```

//Number two represent the index number. Here it is the 3rd frame,which can be identified using pageSource. 
Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete  WORKING code 
`

```
    driver.get("http://www.paytm.com");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In / Sign Up")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.switchTo().frame(1);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='input_0']")).sendKeys(
            "email");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='input_1']")).sendKeys(
            "passwrd");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/div/md-content/button[1]"))
            .click();`
```